# Similar Slider in Jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, gallery

I was looking in Google for similar Main slider to the one in this website : http://www.coxarchitecture.com.au

You can see in the home page how the image is moving like a camera effect and fade in out later with description

Do u guys know any script or can guide me how to add such an effect using JQuery

Comment: that is flash. they created using flash, n u can https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=jquery+sliders

Comment: I know it's flash that's why I asked if I can find a similar script using JQuery and I've already looked in almost all the Google links related to JQuery sliders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm hesitant to just do a search for you,

http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/

Check out the examples towards the bottom.

Comment: Thank you lucuma, I swear I googled alot for it I just couldn't find the right word to search for..you made my day lucuma thanks again :)

Comment: Having implemented more sliders than I care to admit I knew exactly how to search for it.  The effect is called pan or panning image.  Good luck!